# Adding multiple entries to a storage queue via java azure function app

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I appreciate that at the moment the Java support in Azure Functions is preview, but I'm wondering if the functionality is missing or if it can't find it.

The problem I'm trying to solve is as follows. Create an HTTPTriger that will receive a date parameter and then read a Blob store and place the URIs of all blobs that start with the parameter (and end with .qmsg) onto a queue for further processing.

the C# sample code shows the following pattern, using the ICollector.

```
public static class ICollectorExample
{
    [FunctionName("CopyQueueMessageICollector")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items-source-3")] string myQueueItem,
        [Queue("myqueue-items-destination")] ICollector<string> myDestinationQueue,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        myDestinationQueue.Add($"Copy 1: {myQueueItem}");
        myDestinationQueue.Add($"Copy 2: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

The Java ducument says to use OutputBinding<T>, however this appears to only have a .setValue(<T>) method and if I use OutputBinding<string>  only one of my items ends up on the queue.

So what Should I use to ensure that I get both?

Nick(c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use `List<String>` as  T value instead of `String`. See following code sample.

```
public class QueueTriggerJava {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when a new message is received at the specified path. The message contents are provided as input to this function.
     */
    @FunctionName("QueueTriggerJava")
    public void queueHandler(
        @QueueTrigger(name = "message", queueName = "input-queue-items", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") String message,
        @QueueOutput(name = "outMessages", queueName = "outout-queue-items", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") OutputBinding<List<String>> outMessages,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        List<String> allMessages = new LinkedList<String>();
        allMessages.add(message);
        allMessages.add(message);
        outMessages.setValue(allMessages);
        context.getLogger().info("Message count: " + outMessages.getValue().size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Jerry. Odd thing is I'd tried that and was getting an error saying the parameter couldn't be resolved to a string (or some such). But in the end that was because I'd not updated my test!!!